# How to read a text file and create a nested List(or Tuple) structure creating an individual nested list for the contents of each readline

Tags: python

I have small Python script that reads a file and builds a list. It works just fine.  The issue I am having is that the script is building one list encompassing the entire file.  I would like it to build individual nested lists of the contents of each readline and encase these nested lists into a single upper-level list..

Here s my code:

```
filename = "locations.txt"

with open(filename) as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]

# printing the data
print(lines)
#filename.close()
```

my input file looks like this:

```
35.604790, -105.998880, Main Campus
35.135750, -106.520126, Montoya
35.301460, -106.726128, Rio Rancho
35.1502336, -106.57792, STEMULUS Center
35.184371, -106.595124, ATC
```

Here is the current output that I am getting:

```
['35.604790, -105.998880, Main Campus', '35.135750, -106.520126, Montoya', '35.301460, -106.726128, Rio Rancho', '35.1502336, -106.57792, STEMULUS 
Center', '35.184371, -106.595124, ATC']
```

I would like the output to appear as such:

```
[[35.604790, -105.998880, 'Main Campus'], [35.135750, -106.520126, 'Montoya'], [35.301460, -106.726128, 'Rio Rancho], [35.1502336, -106.57792, 'STEMULUS 
Center'], [35.184371, -106.595124, 'ATC']]
```

The first two elements of the individual lists are floats. The last element is text.

I have searched Google and I have tried various solutions listed here, but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Since your input is really a CSV file with insignificant spaces after each comma, you can use `csv.reader` with the `skipinitialspace` option for the purpose:

```
import csv

filename = "locations.txt"

with open(filename) as file:
    output = [
        [float(x), float(y), location]
        for x, y, location in csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
    ]
print(output)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/DizzyShowyPrediction

Comment: And possibly `location.removesuffix('<br/>')`